# Changing cube splitter's reflection% with paint

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser

[image]

Hi folks, I need beam #2 to be reflected as close to 100% as possible, while ALSO allowing beam #1 to be transmitted through as close to 100% as possible.
Will black paint on side 3 alow this? Or is what I'm after not a cube splitter at all but a mirror of some type.

Comment: Black paint on side 3 won’t achieve either objective.